# What is the Delphi equivalent to C++'s memset?

Tags: c++, delphi

Is sz an array of char, also what is the memset pointing to in the buffer? How can I convert the following C++ code to Delphi?

```
int data = _ttoi(m_Strtag.GetBuffer(0));
unsigned char sz[4];
memset(sz,0, 4);
sz[0] = (unsigned char)((data >> 24) & 0xFF);
sz[1] = (unsigned char)((data >> 16) & 0xFF);
sz[2] = (unsigned char)((data >> 8) & 0xFF);
sz[3] = (unsigned char)(data & 0xFF);
```

This is the delphi call:
    if SAAT_YTagSelect(hp, isenable, 1, sz, 4) then ...

for the following delphi function:

```
function SAAT_YTagSelect(pHandle: Pointer; nOpEnable1, nMatchType: Byte; MatchData: PByte; nLenth: Byte): Boolean; stdcall;
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y9ZvzNMX

Comment: `FillChar` is the equivalent. Do you really want us to translate the rest of the code for you? Do you understand bitwise operations?

Comment: All bytes in sz is set afterwards, no need to preset them with zero. And anding with $FF can be removed.

Comment: @LU yes, memset can be removed. The & 0xff ensures we avoid range errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, enclosing with Byte() avoids range errors as well.

Comment: In this particular example, you can also use Microsoft's `ZeroMemory()` instead of Delphi's `FillChar()`.

Comment: @Remy Interestingly that is implemented with a call to FillChar. I guess ZeroMemory is a macro that calls memset.

Comment: There is also `FillMemory()`, which is more closer to what `memset()` actually does - fill memory with a specified value. But it also delegates to `FillChar()` (which really operates on bytes and not characters, so it is really misnamed in D2009 onwards).

Comment: I did understand the FillChar is the equivalent of mmeset, Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent to `memset` is [FillChar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.FillChar) and fills a range of bytes with a byte value.

Since all bytes in the array `sz` is set when the byte order of `data` is reversed, this line can be removed.

The byte reversal can be simplified a little (replacing `and $FF` with a type restriction):

```
data := StrToInt(aString);
sz[0] := Byte(data shr 24);
sz[1] := Byte(data shr 16);
sz[2] := Byte(data shr 8);
sz[3] := Byte(data);
```

---

By enclosing the assignment with `Byte()`, the compiler is told to skip range checking.
A comparison of the generated assembly code (with range checking on) reveals that this also produces a more efficient code:

```
Project1.dpr.36: sz[0] := Byte(data shr 24);   
0041C485 A1BC3E4200       mov eax,[$00423ebc]
0041C48A C1E818           shr eax,$18
0041C48D A2C03E4200       mov [$00423ec0],al


Project1.dpr.40: sz[0] := (data shr 24) and $FF;  
0041C485 A1BC3E4200       mov eax,[$00423ebc]
0041C48A C1E818           shr eax,$18
0041C48D 25FF000000       and eax,$000000ff
0041C492 3DFF000000       cmp eax,$000000ff
0041C497 7605             jbe $0041c49e
0041C499 E8F290FEFF       call @BoundErr
0041C49E A2C03E4200       mov [$00423ec0],al
```

---

A more direct way of populating the sz array, without the bitshifting routines:

```
sz[0] := PByte(@data)[3];
sz[1] := PByte(@data)[2];
sz[2] := PByte(@data)[1];
sz[3] := PByte(@data)[0];
```

Comment: Are you sure this won't lead to errors with range checking?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes I double checked :)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the issues around bitwise shift operators on signed values. The code in the question looks dubious to say the least.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you mean that in C/C++ the behaviour of the `>>` operator is implementation-defined on signed values and has to be checked. It can be an arithmetic shift or a logical shift. In this example it has no relevance since the end result will be the same.